# this sweet alert i want to save data to my localhost but its not save and always looking for url: rootURL + "api/v1/case/add",

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweet.js

```
function submitCreateCaseForm($formStatus) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: "Do you want to save the changes?",
        showDenyButton: true,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Save",
        denyButtonText: `Don't save`,
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            $("#form_status").val($formStatus);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: rootURL + "api/v1/case/add",
                data: $("#msform").serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    if (
                        response === "Case successfully created and submitted"
                    ) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: "success",
                            title: "Saved!",
                            html: `<center>Case successfully created and submitted.</center>`,
                        });
                        $("#error-form").empty();
                        location.assign(
                            rootURL + "admin/case-folder/master-list"
                        );
                    } else if (
                        response === "Case successfully saved as draft"
                    ) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: "success",
                            title: "Saved!",
                            html: `<center>Case successfully saved as draft.</center>`,
                        });
                        $("#error-form").empty();
                        location.assign(
                            rootURL + "admin/case-folder/master-list"
                        );
                    } else if (
                        response ===
                        `Sorry you don't have the rights to create case please contact the administrator`
                    ) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: "error",
                            title: "Error!",
                            html: `<center>Sorry you don't have the rights to create case please contact the administrator.</center>`,
                        });
                        $("#error-form").empty();
                        location.assign(
                            rootURL + "admin/case-folder/master-list"
                        );
                    } else {
                        Swal.fire("The case was not created!", "", "error");

                        html = "";
                        $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                            html +=
                                '<p class="d-flex justify-content-center text-danger">' +
                                value +
                                "</p>";
                        });
                        html += "<hr>";

                        $("#error-form").empty().prepend(html);
                    }
                },
            });
        } else if (result.isDenied) {
            Swal.fire("Changes are not saved", "", "info");
        }
    });
}
```

I want to save data to my localhost but it's not saving and always looking for url: rootURL + "api/v1/case/add",